# difference between GL_SAMPLES_PASSED and GL_ANY_SAMPLES_PASSED in occlusion query

Tags: opengl

I know what a query object is but I dont quite fully understand the difference between GL_SAMPLES_PASSED and GL_ANY_SAMPLES_PASSED. The reference page says this about GL_ANY_SAMPLES_PASSED: Subsequent rendering causes the flag to be set to GL_TRUE if "any" sample passes the depth test in the case of GL_ANY_SAMPLES_PASSED.

So does this mean, the only diffferences are that, query object with GL_ANY_SAMPLES_PASSED is much faster because it does not have to count the number of samples that passed, it simply returns true/false instead of a count and this is also helpful in conditional rendering (because of true false value).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether `GL_ANY_SAMPLES_PASSED` is faster than `GL_SAMPLES_PASSED` or not is unknown. Neither way will be faster in terms of rendering, as you can't know what the answer is until the entire test has completed rendering through the pipeline.

It's not even really for [conditional rendering scenarios](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Conditional_rendering), because they can both be used for that. You can use conditional rendering with `GL_SAMPLES_PASSED` and achieve the same effect; they use the same true/false condition (ie: conditional with `GL_SAMPLES_PASSED` is considered to pass if the sample count is > 0).

The difference is that one gives you more information than the other. The any query might be more efficient to compute; that is, `GL_SAMPLES_PASSED` might have some non-trivial rasterization overhead that `GL_ANY_SAMPLES_PASSED` does not. Then again, it may not. It would vary with the hardware.

Use whichever one serves your needs. If you need a sample count, ask for one. If all you need to know is whether it passed, then use that.

Comment: I don't know if that has changed this you wrote that answer. But as far as I know `GL_SAMPLES_PASSED` is the amount of samples that pass the depth test, whereas `GL_SAMPLES_PASSED` is all the generated samples, no matter if they passed the depth test or not.